# Sort Order vs Display Sort Order

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an app that displays a section title followed by the detail items followed by the next section and its details.  Everything works fine, but I would like to rearrange the order in which the sections are shown.  The problem is that I need to order the core data by the report-id then status then the date to get the correct detail items to show under the proper section.

```
let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Item.report.id), ascending:true)
let sortDescriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Item.report.status), ascending:true)
let sortDescriptor3 = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Item.report.dateStarted), ascending:false)
let sortDescriptor4 = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Item.date), ascending:true)
```

How can I change the sort/display order while still maintaining the proper relationship between the section (report) and the detail items associated with it?  The report.id is a UUID so currently the reports end up in random order.

Comment: What order do you want the sections to appear in?  Are you using NSFetchedResultsController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fetchedResultsController has a property `sectionNameKeyPath` which can be used to group items togethers.  This only works if the `sectionNameKeyPath` groups the items in the same order that they are sorted.  For example: you can sort by date and then group by `hour` or `week` or any other time based grouping, but not by `name`.  In your case you want the sections to be sorted in a way that does not not match how the items are grouped.  There may be some clever solution for your particular situation, but since you didn't give any details I can only give a general solution.

The `indexPath` that is returned from a fetchedResultsController is really useful for interoperability with a tableView or collectionView.  But it does not have to be a one-to-one relationship.  For example you could have a setup where one section points to one fetchedResultsController and another section points to a different one.  The key in doing this setup is to make sure to not confuse the fetchedResultsController indexPath with your collectionView indexPath.  Generally I find having a separate object to manage converting the indexPath the easily way to keep it straight.

Create a separate object that sorts the sections after the fetchedResultsController does a fetch (and after a section is inserted or deleted).  Inside the `indexPathsManager` have a dictionary the maps between the "local" indexPath and the fetchedResultsController indexPath. Make sure to sure use this object EVERY TIME you use indexPaths in the viewController.  Also make sure to convert the indexPaths when you update the view after the fetchedResultsController delegates that there is a change.  And updating the indexPathsManager when any sections are inserted or deleted.

**TL;DR** Sort the sections of the fetchedResultsController after the fetch and convert your tableView's indexPath to fetchedResultsController indexPaths.